# How to say "Mathematics has a great impact on technology."?

Tags: grammar

I have looked related examples up from the internet and I found some patterns as follows.

What I want to say is

> *Mathematics has a great impact (influence) on technology.*

or

> *Technology is greatly impacted (influenced) by mathematics.*

My attempts are as follows but I am confused in choosing the best one.

- A: 数学が技術に大きな影響をする。
- B: 数学が技術に大きな影響を与える。
- C: 数学が技術に大きな影響力を持つ。
- D: 数学が技術に大きな影響を及ぼす。
- E: 数学が技術に大きな影響を齎す。
- F: 数学は技術に大きな影響がある。
- G: **技術**が数学に**大きく**影響される。
- H: **技術**が数学に大きな影響を受ける。

Bonus: If you have any other expressions, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly there is the issue of using [「テクノロジー」](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/151214/meaning/m0u/) or 「技術」. 
Using either is fine, but I thought you should be aware there are other possibilities for your question.

Some more food for thought.

- 数学がテクノロジーに強い影響を与える
- 数学が技術に強い影響力がある
- 数学がテクノロジーに強い影響力がある
- 数学がテクノロジーに大きな影響を与える

As for yours, the below is not used, in this instance 「をする」 does not make sense.

- A: 数学が技術に大きな影響**をする**。

This should be 「は」 not 「が」.

- G: 技術**は**数学に大きく影響される。

And this would be better as 「は」, although depending on the context you could also use 「が」.

- H: 技術**は**数学に大きな影響を受ける。

Other than that any of the others would be fine. It is hard to choose which the best one.

Comment: @YasashiiEirian, LOL , typo.